# How to make instantiated gameObject to be child of other object

Tags: unity, c#

I have a game object that I want to instantiate. There is no problem at all with the `Instantiate()` method. But the problem is, whenever I instantiate the object I want it to be a child of another object (like in the hierarchy). For example, a keyboard object is a child of a notebook object in the hierarchy.

Whenever I instantiate the keyboard, I want it to be a child of the notebook object.

How to do this?

Comment: I assume you took a look at the documentation, found this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html and you do not know how to use it? The second `Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by user Zibelas, you can use the `Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent)` function to instantiate an object. This will immediately set `parent` as its parent after its creation, thus it will become a child of the `parent` Transform. Usage:

```
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(originalPrefab, newParent);
```

This is equivalent to doing this:

```
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(originalPrefab);
newObject.transform.SetParent(newParent);
```